# Ordering an Array with weights?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, drupal-6, drupal-modules

### The problem

Right now I have to create this:
 [image: Module]

In my database; each favorite as its own 'weight' entry.
As of right now it defaults to '10'

Let's say I have an array of favorites,
the weights go like this accordingly:

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4

If I were to press the 'down' arrow on '2' I'd have to add +1 to its weight.
Which would result in:

- 1
- 3
- 3
- 4

But I just want to switch favorite '2' with favorite '3's weight.
I need a way to ensure that when the weights for each item function as they're implied.
Since just adding or subtracting 1 will lead to a lot of problem.

Hopefully I explained it properly.

### The code

Writing to the database

```
/*
 * Write Form data to database
 */
function f25_favorites_form_submit($form, &$form_state){
  global $user;
  $listOfPaths = f25_favorites_listOfPaths();
  $selected = $form_state['values']['path'];

  $data = array(
    'uid' => $user->uid,
    'path' => $selected,
    'title' => $listOfPaths[$selected]['#title'],
    'weight' => 10,
    'timestamp' => time(),
  );

  drupal_write_record(f25_favorites, $data);
}
```

The Query

```
/*
 * Fetching Specific User's Favorites Data
 */
function f25_favorites_user_favorites() {
  global $user;
  if($user->uid > 0){
    $userid = $user->uid;
    $user_paths = db_query("SELECT * FROM f25_favorites foo WHERE foo.uid = '%s' ORDER BY foo.weight DESC", $userid);
      $pathlist = array();
    while ($data = db_fetch_object($user_paths)) {
      $pathlist[] = $data;
    }
    return $pathlist;
  }
}
```

How should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 2):

if all your favorites are weighted differently, you can simply swap the `weight` field of the one "getting up" with the one "getting down", or reverse, when decreasing weight. you'd have to figure out the code though

Comment: I think this idea has some merit; I think I'll try it out.

Answer (score 1):

as there are only little items I would save the whole order to the database, not only what has been moved.: i don't know much about drupal but i think it would be easy to accomplish as drupal is php and javascript based.

each element in html has its own id/index (uid?)

```
<div id="el_1">Menu1</div>  
<div id="el_2">Menu2</div>
```

use javascript to get list of your items in the reordered order (like:

```
itm[0]=item1;  
itm[1]=item3;  
itm[2]=item2;  
itm[3]=item4;
```

send itm with ajax to your php updater. and update your db, use the position received and not weights.

now your db has something like this:

```
uid;position
1;0
3;1
2;2
4;3
```

I recommend you [jquery](http://jquery.com/) for the javascript work, jquery has a nice [sortable plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/). but it is also awesome for the [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) stuf.